# Software for matrix-product state calculations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, software

Which software packages exist to either numerically or analytically do matrix-product state calculations? (Such as finding the ground state, time evolution, bond decimation, symmetries..) Which are under active development? What are their strengths and weaknesses?

There is a list here: http://quantumtensor.pks.mpg.de/index.php/links/. It is far from complete and does not provide more information about the different packages, but it's a start. For example, I also found [quimb](https://quimb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
and [TensorNetwork](https://github.com/google/TensorNetwork).

Answer (score 1):

Most of modern software can do (or has packages that can do) matrix multiplication, solve eigenvalue problems, etc. On the top of the head one could mention the `Matlab` and the `numpy` module of `Python`. But one needs to understand the underlying matrix algebra to use either of them.

Comment: With the added complexity that one has to write all the code for the specific algorithms by themselves.

Comment: @NDewolf They have most of the necessary matrix routines already built-in. If something is lacking, it is hardly "added complexity". I would even call it "lacking complexity" of trying to understand somebody else's code... and correct their errors.

Comment: I would be surprised if NumPy and Matlab have built-in code for DMRG or TEBD, etc.

Comment: @NDewolf this is not what the question asks, as far as I understand.

Comment: It specifically asks how to find ground states, time evolution, etc. with MPS.

Comment: Thank you @Vadim for your answer. Unfortunately NDewolf is right, and I'm asking about packages that implement algorithms such as DMRG or TEBD, not mere matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Daniel I have mistaken "matrix product" and "matrix product state" - the latter has very specific meaning, unlike the former. I suggest that you add more content to your answer, e.g., describing what type of problem you are trying to solve. It may help to generate more attention/responses.

Comment: @NDewolf Python library to solve spin and fermionic Hamiltonians with DMRG [from dmrgpy import spinchain](https://github.com/joselado/dmrgpy)